# How to join array into string in Julia

Tags: string, julia

How can I join [5, 'N', 'K', 'r', 9, 'j', 'K', '(', 'E', 't'] into making it a single string like this "5NKr9jK(Et"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `join` it :):

```
julia> join([5, 'N', 'K', 'r', 9, 'j', 'K', '(', 'E', 't'])
"5NKr9jK(Et"
```

The individual elements of the vector are converted to string using the `print` function.

Comment: How about this one sir.
I cant return the result variable because i cant call it outside the for loop, any tips?

Comment: define the variable outside of the loop using `global` (in global scope) or `local` (in local scope, e.g. inside a function) keyword. I propose you just ask a separate question for this so that you can get a proper answer more clearly than here in the comment.